# Is there any way to dynamically select a filepath in a windows shortcut?

Tags: windows-10, file-shortcut

My company is using a program that is launched through a particular URL through Chrome. As many of my coworkers are not computer literate, I want to make sure I have working shortcuts to make access as simple as possible

The only issue is that some computers have Chrome installed under "Program Files (x86)" and some are installed under "Program Files", usually on laptops.

Windows does not seem to let me create a shortcut for a program that does not exist for *my* computer, so I need to create the shortcut on one of the laptops and save it on the LAN.

That's my current solution, but for some reason someone deleted the laptop version of the shortcut, meaning that I need to borrow someone else's laptop again, preventing them from working temporarily, to remake the shortcut.

Ideally, to prevent people from deleting what they think is a non-functional shortcut, I want a single shortcut that dynamically selects which file path Chrome is installed under when used.

Is there any way to make a shortcut that can 'option select' the correct filepath?

Comment: How are you installing the shortcut on computers? Will installing a `.bat` script file instead is a possible solution?

Comment: @harrymc It's just a shortcut saved in a folder on the LAN for users to drag and drop onto their desktop

Comment: I usually put the shortcut to Chrome or other programs immediately in the Taskbar. For the rest you can create the shortcut when the guys are getting their PC setup. Another way would be to always use the same installer and to stick with either 64-Bit or 32 bit for everyone. Otherwise to make a quick shortcut, go to the source hold Alt and drag the icon were the shortcut is needed. If you let them setup their own PC, make a fool proof doc, step by step, use lots of pictures.

Comment: @VarmintLP You're not wrong but I'm just joining (this year) a company that has had very relaxed rules about computer usage before I was hired. Ideally everyone would have the same install path, but since everyone installed in themselves without direction the specifics are all over the place. Pending the invention of time travel, I feel that the solution I referenced under LPChip's post works better for my purposes

Comment: Well the only other solution would be to reinstall chrome on each PC to make sure everyone is using the same version etc. Plugs and favorites are stored in the appdata folder and unless specified they will remain there. Or if the users are supposed to do it themselfs then you should provide them with the installer files and thereby ensuring that the path will be always the same from this point on. It's good to trust your users but there should be certain standards to avoid issues. If they need custom then you provide custom if it's allowed by the company rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution is to simply put the following in your script:

```
start https://yoururlhere.com
```

This will open the url in the default browser.

---

If you really need to use chrome, you can do the following:

```
if exist "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" cd /d C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application
if exist "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" cd /d C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application

chrome https://yoururlhere.com
```

Comment: +1 Very silly, but to keep the icon what users are familiar with I made this .bat file and then made the shortcut point to THAT instead

Comment: Yes of course, but I knew you needed help with the .bat (or .cmd) so I only wrote that part. :)

Answer (score 1):

In Windows, there is a filetype called "Internet Shortcut" (the file itself has the extension `.url`). Such files save the URL and use the default browser, whatever it is, to launch the URL. There is thus no need to care where the default browser is installed.

Below you will see screenshots of the first two tabs of File Properties for a `.url` file. The easiest way for me to create such files is to drag from the URL bar in Chrome to the desktop. (click on the https lock or the http "not locked" icon just left of the URL)

[image: screenshot of first tab]
[image: screenshot of second tab]

Comment: +1 I was about to write this in my answer too, but as you already did, I removed that part from my answer.

Comment: Definitely good to know, unfortunately many of my users still insist on having IE or Edge as their default browser, I need to enforce opening in Chrome